# Touchpad causes huge amount of interrupts and high power usage

Tags: drivers, touchpad, 20.04, input, interrupts

I have an issue with the touchpad on my notebook where if I use it, it causes a high amount of interrupts which results in significantly higher CPU usage and power drain. The following snippet is after 5 minutes of powering the device on. Notice the amount of interrupts on IRQ 17 in comparison to the rest.

```
cat /proc/interrupts
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       
   0:          8          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    2-edge      timer
   1:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0       1350  IR-IO-APIC    1-edge      i8042
   8:          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    8-edge      rtc0
   9:          0         31          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    9-fasteoi   acpi
  14:          0          0      14671          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   14-fasteoi   INT344B:00
  16:          0          0          0       6167          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   16-fasteoi   i801_smbus, idma64.0, i2c_designware.0
  17:          0          0          0          0     604999          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   17-fasteoi   idma64.1, i2c_designware.1
  20:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   20-fasteoi   idma64.2
  23:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   23-fasteoi   idma64.3, pxa2xx-spi.3
 120:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  DMAR-MSI    0-edge      dmar0
 121:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  DMAR-MSI    1-edge      dmar1
```

In threads with [similar](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=229881) [issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/8wssyu/idma64_interrupts_causing_high_cpu_clock_and_poor/e1ypd1s/) it was recommended to blacklist `i2c_designware` or `intel_lpss_pci` but neither helped in my case. Using the kernel parameter `initcall_blacklist=dw_i2c_init_driver` as recommended [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423797/how-do-i-disable-i2c-designware-support-when-its-not-built-as-a-module) lead to my touchpad not being recognized at all anymore. There also is no BIOS parameter or something similar to switch trackpad modes. Is there anything else I can try or am I stuck with using my mouse until this is fixed in the kernel?

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep i2c -B2 -A7
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=19ac Version=0100
N: Name="SYNA2393:00 06CB:19AC"
P: Phys=i2c-SYNA2393:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-SYNA2393:00/0018:06CB:19AC.0001/input/input23
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event8 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003
B: MSC=20
--
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=cd48 Version=0100
N: Name="SYNA1D31:00 06CB:CD48 Mouse"
P: Phys=i2c-SYNA1D31:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-SYNA1D31:00/0018:06CB:CD48.0002/input/input27
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
B: MSC=10
--
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=cd48 Version=0100
N: Name="SYNA1D31:00 06CB:CD48 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-SYNA1D31:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-SYNA1D31:00/0018:06CB:CD48.0002/input/input28
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event10 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

```
lspci -nnkv | grep 'IRQ 17' -B3 -A4

00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:9d61] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [19e5:3e04]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 2ff3020000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering the same issue on my laptop for a few years. I noticed it because the CPU was draining the battery/triggering the fan when idle.
The workaround I have used until now was to enter in sleep mode (s3) a few seconds and after the resume, the problem was gone. I was doing that after every reboot but this fix doesn't work anymore.
Initially, I thought that was a problem with the Intel P-State scheduler until I found your question here.

The new workaround for me now is to unload the kernel module.

```
rmmod intel_lpss_pci
```

suspend to ram, wait a few seconds, resume, reload the kernel module

```
modprobe intel_lpss_pci
```

That's getting more and more convoluted, I wish this could be really fixed...

Answer (score 0):

I am:

> 5.4.0-73-generic #82~18.04.1-Ubuntu  x86_64 GNU/Linux

on

> HP Pavilion - 14-ce2014

In my case I have had ACPI-related IRQ storms (related to pinctrl_cannonlake, I presume) from both:

> I915  (Intel graphics)

and this

> INT34BB (Trackpad)

HP drivers.
Both take up to 95% of a CPU core after some minutes.

In the end, after many hours or days wasted hunting the culprit, even BIOS flashing, etc. I discovered that the only working method is masking the interrupt(s), e.g. via adding:

```
acpi_mask_gpe=0x6F
```

to the kernel parameter for the former I915 bug

and the above temporary fix:

```
sudo systemctl suspend
```

(and then just resuming, even without disabling/enabling the offending module) for the latter INT34BB Trackpad one.

Answer (score 0):

Update re the above.

I have also tried:

```
pci=nocrs
```

in the kernel parameters, which supposedly does this: "Ignore PCI host bridge windows from ACPI" and now  I have zero interrupts from INT34BB:

```
 14:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC   14-fasteoi   INT34BB:00
```

even after some hours.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another update:

Neither of them worked long-term.
This one only works, at least since yesterday:
`initcall_blacklist=cnl_pinctrl_driver_init`

as per https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/gdxln8/high_cpu_load_on_a_single_thread/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1178974)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1178974)